# Large stack variables Error when building Anchor project

Tags: anchor, solana-program

This is an error while building Anchor project. anchor build But it was built successfully. I'm not sure if it's because of version compatibility.

`Error: Function _ZN112_$LT$solana_program..instruction..InstructionError$u20$as$u20$solana_frozen_abi..abi_example..AbiEnumVisitor$GT$13visit_for_abi17h2f3c0d426ad8ac9bE Stack offset of 4584 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 488 bytes, please minimize large stack variables`

solana-cli 1.18.1 anchor 0.29.0 rustc 1.76.0

Anyone could help me? Thanks

Comment: Yes, thanks. I solved the problem.